# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum is not saving image to photo album

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, ios6, photo

I m trying to save image from scrollview to photo album when user long press on image, action sheet shows up with save photo button and when hitting save button it is not saving image to photo album

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

{    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 10, 60, 35);

    //[myButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

    myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;

    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    [myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    _imageView.tag = 128;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                       initWithTarget:self
                                                       action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    //imageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [gestureRecognizer release];

    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageScrollView addSubview:myButton];

    //[imageView release];

}
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];
[imageScrollView release];
 }



 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
    [_imageScrollView viewWithTag:128];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);//When i add breakpoint at this statement in result it shows storage zero but alert view says success photo got saved in photo album

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
 {
if (error != NULL)
{

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
     } else{
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
   }
   }
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logging anything? Why do you have 2 semicolons ;; at the end of your UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Hard to tell only from the code that you have provided

Comment: Put up a break point on didFinishSavingWithError and see where it goes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17766/discussion-between-user1452248-and-s-p)

Comment: Have you check that photo is there in your photos library or not.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with privacy settings - people have been having this problem with my app and no error message is reported. In theory attempting to save a photo should automatically ask the user if the app should be allowed to access their photos however in some cases the user will need to go to Settings > Privacy > Photos and ensure your app is allowed.